# isset method not working. Please see the code am stuck in wierd situation

Tags: php, html

The `isset` method does not work for me. Please see the code, I am stuck in weird situation: when I click on login nothing is happening while clicking on register is...

returning register as output !.  sorry if this qstn is stupid ..

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['register'])){
echo "register";}
if (isset($_POST['login'])){
echo "login";}
?>
<form action= "" method="post"  > 
<input type="submit" name="Login"  value="login" />
</form>

<form action= "" method="post"  > 

<input type="submit" name="register"  />


</form>
```

Comment: Trying taking out `action=""`, then try.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<input type="submit" name="Login"  value="login" />
```

To

```
<input type="submit" name="login"  value="login" />
```

Note the capital L. The array key in `$_POST` is case sensitive.

Comment: thankyou so so much @cowls it was a silly mistake ...but i was stuck at this for last 2 hrs ..

Comment: Never mind, just keep this in mind in future and you wont make the same mistake again :)

Answer (score 1):

You're testing for lowercase `login`, but the name of the element in the HTML is `Login`.

If you change the name of your login button to "login" instead, it will work as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need the line

```
<input type="submit" name="login"  value="login" />
```

Your code is looking for the name of the button and you had a capital letter in the wrong place!

Comment: thankyou kat i got the solution will be careful in future about those silly mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Array keys are case-sensitive.

Try 
    "if (isset($_POST['Login'])){"

Note your Login button has the name "Login"

Answer (score 0):

Check the letters, you have used small letter in the form and are checking for the capital letter in the php condition

```
if (isset($_POST['Login'])){
```

either change the `<input type="submit" name="Login"  value="login" />` to `<input type="submit" name="Login"  value="Login" />` or change  `if (isset($_POST['Login'])){` to  `if (isset($_POST['login'])){`

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<input type="submit" name="Login"  value="login" />
```

with that:

```
<input type="submit" name="login"  value="login" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Login needs to be lowercase.

Register needs a value.